# Error converting data type varchar to int.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table is below

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
     CustomerID int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
     Name varchar(50) not null,
     PhoneNumber varchar(20) not null 
         constraint chk_PhoneNumber check(PhoneNumber not like '%[^0-9]%'),
     DoorNo varchar(50) not null,
     StreetName varchar(50) not null,
     City varchar(50) not null,
     Statee varchar(50) not null,
     Zipcode int not null
)
```

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE stp_customers_insert
    (@customerid int, 
     @name varchar(50),
     @phone varchar(50),
     @doorno varchar(50),
     @streetname varchar(50),
     @city varchar(50),
     @state varchar(50),
     @zip int)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @customerid)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('employee id already exists', 1, 1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Customers (Name, PhoneNumber, DoorNo, StreetName, City, Statee, Zipcode) 
        VALUES (@name, @phone, @doorno, @streetname, @city, @state, @zip)
    END
END
```

Sample call:

```
exec stp_customers_insert 'ram', '674673932', '122', '5th cross', 'trichy', 'tamilnadu', 620001
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure stp_customers_insert, Line 23
>   Error converting data type varchar to int.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that your stored procedure expects 8 parameters:

```
stp_customers_insert(@customerid int, @name varchar(50), @phone varchar(50),
                     @doorno varchar(50), @streetname varchar(50), @city varchar(50),
                     @state varchar(50), @zip int)
```

but you are only passing 7 parameters when you actually call the proc:

```
exec stp_customers_insert 'ram','674673932','122','5th cross','trichy','tamilnadu',620001
```

If you don't know or don't want to perform the duplicate check on the `CustomerID`, then you could slightly modify your call to just pass `NULL`:

```
exec stp_customers_insert NULL, 'ram','674673932','122','5th cross','trichy','tamilnadu',620001
```

As an aside, if the proc is not even inserting the `CustomerID`, and this field is auto increment, then I don't see the point of passing it.  Instead, you might want to consider using a unique constraint to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
exec stp_customers_insert 1,'ram','674673932','122','5thcross','trichy','tamilnadu',620001
```

You have to pass `@customerid` value in procedure parameters - then it will execute without error.

Answer (score -1):

In your table structure `CustomerID` is defined as `INT`. But as your stored procedure is defined in this format:

`stp_customers_insert(@customerid int,@name ....`

You are sending `ram` as value for `customerid` in

`exec stp_customers_insert 'ram','674673932'....`

Correct this to:

`exec stp_customers_insert '*enter the CustId value here*','ram','674673932'....`

Replace `*enter the CustId value here*` with the `CustomerID`

Also change:

```
insert into Customers(Name,PhoneNumber,DoorNo,StreetName,City,Statee,Zipcode) values(@name,@phone,@doorno,@streetname,@city,@state,@zip)
```

To include `CustomerID` as:

```
insert into Customers(CustomerID,Name,PhoneNumber,DoorNo,StreetName,City,Statee,Zipcode) values(@customerid,@name,@phone,@doorno,@streetname,@city,@state,@zip)
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest remove `@customerid` from sp `CustomerID` is auto increment field so no need to pass any value for `CustomerID`. It should be like this:

```
alter procedure stp_customers_insert(@name varchar(50),@phone varchar(50),@doorno varchar(50),@streetname varchar(50),@city varchar(50),@state varchar(50),@zip int)
as
    begin
    if exists(select CustomerID from Customers where Name = @name ,phone = @phone ,doorno = @doorno ,streetname = @streetname ,city= @city,state= @state , zip = @zip )
    begin
        raiserror('employee id already exists',1,1)
    end
else
    begin
        insert into Customers(Name,PhoneNumber,DoorNo,StreetName,City,Statee,Zipcode) values(@name,@phone,@doorno,@streetname,@city,@state,@zip)
    end
end

exec stp_customers_insert 'ram','674673932','122','5th cross','trichy','tamilnadu',620001
```

Comment: why is this downvote? It is only one alternate answer and i am sure my answer can solve the error. Pls explain.